# Why does ubuntu consume 1/4 of the CPUs while beeing idle?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am experiencing unusual CPU usage on a ubuntu 14.04.03 box which is supposed to be idle. It is around 25% on a 4 core system and htop says load is about 1.0 while the underlying proccess all show 0 to a bit % CPU load.

There are no special services running as I stoped all of them to identify the cause. The high CPU consumption now holds for over 12 hours.

How can I determine the process eating up a 1/4 of the CPU power?

This is a screen shot of htop:

[image]

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: That looks like a container, not a full virtual machine.

Comment: What do you mean? This is a screenshot of htop running on a full VM.

Comment: All the kernel threads are missing. That is not expected behavior on a VM. But it is normal for a container. Are you sure this isn't a container? How do you know? Have you checked?

Comment: I know this because I have set it up. It is running on virtualbox as node2. node1 and 3 have a similar setup and until recently there was no problem. Also the node functions as it should. I have stoped all services like solr, glusterfs and similar to find the problem and this is what the screenshot shows. After rebooting the problem remains.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you have an idea how to fix this? What do you mean by kernel threads?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by zookeeper as it had a corrupt db. "top" in comparison to "htop" showed 25% CPU for zookeeper.